# difficulty in setting activity orientation dynamically

Tags: android

I am setting activity orientation landscape dynamically in onCreate function. Its working fine. But the problem is that some time for a while activity is shown portrait and then changes to landscape. How can i avoid the transition from portrait to landscape.
I am using setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);.

Thanks.

Comment: that's because you do it in code. is there a particular reason?

Comment: i have to support sensor orientation, but its available on gingerbread onwords.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your activities declaration in the manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: For my app i have to support sensorOrientation also for that i have to check api level dynamically and set the orientation because sensorOrientation support is available only api level 8 onwords.

Comment: Well I don't know of any other method to achieve instant landscape. But if you are setting orientation on changed phone orientation manually (that's how I understand your comment) you can implement all needed code there, thus still supporting sensorOrientation, or do I miss something?